# Meteor Template.[name] is not defined

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm restructuring my Meteor/Blaze app to keep related items in 'modules'. But I'm experiencing an issue with the first template.

My file structure is this:

```
/imports
  /modules
    index.js
    /admin
      index.js
      methods.js
      /client
        adminPage.html
        adminPage.js
```

The index.js files are loading fine. The `adminPage.js` is being imported alongside `adminPage.html`. But when I created `Template.adminPage.onCreated(...)` I got an error message, that I cannot call a function on undefined.

Calling `console.log(Template)` in the `adminPage.js` file returns this:
[Section showing the admin page in console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxOy8.png).

But if I run `console.log(Template.adminPage)` I get `undefined`. I'm not sure what to look for next.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Instead of the correct:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
```

I used

```
import Template from 'meteor/templating';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing an import statement in `/imports/modules/admin/client/adminPage.js`.  At the top of this file add the following:

```
import './adminPage.html';
```

Comment: No, it's there.